# Add a form before Mainform

Tags: forms, delphi

I would like to program a small advertising form, which let's me easily implement it to any of my other projects.
The ad form should appear before my real project/app starts.

Some requirements have to be met:

1. Easy to implement to any project without any hassle - add form/unit and almost everything takes care of the rest.
2. My app's MainForm (Application.MainForm) shall be created during runtime AFTER my ad form has been successfully closed (or requirements have been met)
3. Adding only 1 unit/form should be enough to implement

My progress so far is:

1. I create an empty main form which is hidden (Application.MainForm)
2. Then I create a modalform, which is the actual Ad-Form - on the right modalresult, free my welcomescreen and proceed to the "main app"
3. I need to remove all auto-create forms from my project
4. I open a procedure in my project's source file with some parameters, including the app's main form (see source)
5. Unfortunately I have to add all units/forms to the project instead of just one (recursive path problem?)

That's what I have so far:

Project Source:

```
program MyTestProgram;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Windows,
  uMainWindow in 'uMainWindow.pas' {Form1},
  uEmptyForm in '..\AdProject\uEmptyForm.pas' {AdEmptyMainForm},
  uWelcomeScreen in '..\AdProject\uWelcomeScreen.pas' {WelcomeScreen}; // shouldn't be here

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.Run;
  LoadAdWindow('Title of my app', uMainWindow.TForm1, uMainWindow.Form1);
end.
```

EmptyForm Unit:

```
unit uEmptyForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TAdEmptyMainForm = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  AdEmptyMainForm: TAdEmptyMainForm;

  procedure LoadAdWindow (Appname: string; InstanceClass: TComponentClass; var Reference);

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

  uses
    uWelcomeScreen; // Has to be added to the project, otherwise it doesn't detect the unit in the same path as this unit

  procedure LoadAdWindow (Appname: string; InstanceClass: TComponentClass; var Reference);
  begin
    Application.MainFormOnTaskbar   := True;
    Application.ShowMainForm        := False;
    Application.Title               := Appname;
    Application.CreateForm(TAdEmptyMainForm, AdEmptyMainForm);
    with uWelcomeScreen.TWelcomeScreen.Create(Application.MainForm) do
    begin
      Caption := Appname;
      if ShowModal <> 1337 then ExitProcess(0);
      Free;
    end;
    Application.CreateForm(InstanceClass, Reference);
  end;

end.
```

After the welcome screen succeeds, the application closes.
Is this even the right way to it?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can call that advertising form inside create of your main form.

Comment: @William Why didn't I think of that before? *facepalm* Edit: What about additional units? I would like to keep the forms/units separated but I need to add all forms to my project, instead of just 1

Comment: Why? you can just add the advertising form on other projects and do the same logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Application.MainForm` is established by the first call to `Application.CreateForm()` for a `TForm`-derived class.  `Application.Run()` exits immediately if `Application.MainForm` is not assigned.

To do what you are attempting, you should do it more like the following instead.  You don't need a blank MainForm, simply create and show the ad window before creating the real MainForm. Only the project main source needs to be changed:

```
program MyTestProgram;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Windows,
  uMainWindow in 'uMainWindow.pas' {Form1},
  uWelcomeScreen in '..\AdProject\uWelcomeScreen.pas' {WelcomeScreen};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.Title := 'Title of my app';

  with TWelcomeScreen.Create(Application) do
  try
    Caption := Application.Title;
    if ShowModal <> 1337 then
      Exit;
  finally
    Free;
  end;

  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: I would like to add an additional form in my welcome screen unit. The additional form is also in the same path as the welcome screen. How can I declare this in the uses clause without adding each additional form to my main project?

Comment: Any Form used by the project must be added to the project.  Unless you move them to a runtime package and then use that instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily create and show the Ad Form and after it create and show the main form, like this :

```
var
 FAdFrm : TAdFrm;

begin
 FAdFrm := TAdFrm.Create(nil);
 if FAdFrm.ShowModal = mrOK then
  begin
   FAdFrm.Free;

   Application.Initialize;
   Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
   Application.CreateForm(TMainFrm, MainFrm);

   Application.Run;
  end
 else
  FAdFrm.Free;
```

Be careful that the Main Form of your project is the first form that created with `Application.CreateForm` method

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to create the advertising form on MainForm's create event. I do this on my own projects.

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AdvForm := TAdvForm.Create(Self); 
  Try
    AdvForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    AdvForm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That still creates the MainForm. It is clear from the question that if the Ad window does not return an expected value, the app should terminate. Ideally, the MainForm should not be created at all if it is not going to be used. But, to terminate the app from the MainForm's `OnCreate` event, you can call `Application.Terminate()` (and set `Application.ShowMainForm=False` so the MainForm will not appear briefly before the terminate request is processed).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see, is not the best way to do it, it's just an alternative, i appreaciate your comment.